# scanf printf malfunction in C++, code excerpt from "Competitive Programming 4"

Tags: c++

In CP4 there is a problem statement requiring N number of inputs of the format "0.123..." where input terminates at "...". Upon input end, the program must output the floating-point number that was entered (without the three dots).
The given problem solution was the following:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int N;
    scanf("%d\n", &N);
    while (N--) {
        char x[110];
        scanf("0.%[0-9]...\n", &x); //some compilers gave me an error over '&'
        printf("the digits are 0.%s\n", x);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However, instead of the expected output, it runs the loop N+1 times and displays as such:

```
3
0.1227...
0.517611738...
the digits are 0.1227
0.7341231223444344389923899277...
the digits are 0.517611738
....
```

I tried rewriting the `scanf` in the while loop  without the newline `\n`. This solved the issue on codeblocks but not on vscode (or any other compiler for that matter really) as it ended up terminating the while loop after first input and outputting N duplicates of first output.

What is the fix, if any, that would make the code run as intended?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages.  Do not tag a question with both C and C++ tags unless you're particularly fond of downvotes (or are asking about a difference between C and C++, or how to make them interwork).  I've removed the C tag since the question title mentions C++ and the code uses C++ headers and syntax — it cannot be C code.

Comment: If you replace `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` (which isn't standard C++) and `using namespace std;` (which isn't sound C++) with the normal `#include <stdio.h>` you'll have a straight C program, and can ask the C folks, who probably understand format specifiers better than folks here, how to fix the program. C++ code would take a different approach.

Comment: You don't want the &. Letting x decay to a pointer gives you what you want. Look up array to pointer decay. x will decay to a char * which is the right type here. With the ampersand , the type of the result is pointer to array of 110 char's, not the right type. Both will have the same value, so both will generally work in practice.

Comment: If this code came from a book I'd get rid of the book. Remove `\n` from the format strings, change `&x` to `x`, and put a space before the second format string like `" 0.%[0-9]..."` to skip leading whitespace. https://godbolt.org/z/W8f66Ka63

Comment: @RetiredNinja you're a lifesaver, thank you so much! The authors had 4 editions to get this right, yet here we are.

Comment: @Meiuxx Fear not, the 5th edition will be written by ChatGPT...

Comment: [What is the effect of trailing white space in a scanf() format string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19499060/what-is-the-effect-of-trailing-white-space-in-a-scanf-format-string) explains the behavior of a trailing newline in the format string. It isn't necessarily wrong, it is well-defined what it does, but it is unintuitive if you're providing input at a keyboard. [scanf() leaves the newline character in the buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-newline-character-in-the-buffer) explains the space before the `%[]` specifier.

Comment: These competitions are a waste of your time. Worse actually — they teach you habits which in the real life you will have to work hard to get rid of.

Comment: Never [`#include <bits/stdc++.h>`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/995714), and [Don't use "using namespace std;"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/995714)

Comment: @RetiredNinja: ...which will make the code such a mess nobody will even be able to figure out how to fix any of it.